# Fragment is overlapping other fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, fragment, fragmenttransaction

In my attempt to switch between fragments, I am seeing them stack on top of one another. I know this is supposed to be fixed by dynamically adding fragments, but when I tried that, the problem persisted.

This is the top of my SocksAndUndies Class, and my onCreate method (Which is my FragmentActivity, containing my NavigationView):

```
public class SocksAndUndies extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        FragmentJSON fragmentJSON;
        FragmentTransaction ft;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_socks_and_undies);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    fragmentJSON = new FragmentJSON();
    ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.socksAndUndies, fragmentJSON, "fragmentJSON");
    ft.commit();
}
```

This is the method which I use to change Fragments:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        FragmentTransaction ft;
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            EventsFragment eventsFragment = new EventsFragment();
            ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.socksAndUndies, eventsFragment, "EventsFragment");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.socksAndUndies, fragmentJSON, "fragmentJSON");
        )
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;    
}
```

This is my View:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/socksAndUndies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see a few problems here, don't know if they're related with the one you pointed out though.
In your `onNavigationItemSelected` method, you are missing a closing bracket and an `ft.commit` command.
Here is what that would look like:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    FragmentTransaction ft;
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        EventsFragment eventsFragment = new EventsFragment();            
        ft.replace(R.id.socksAndUndies, eventsFragment, "EventsFragment");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        ft.replace(R.id.socksAndUndies, fragmentJSON, "fragmentJSON");
    }
    ft.commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;    
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I have those things in my code, I inserted this snippit into my code and it behaved in the same way it did before. No change.